# How to enable deflate content-encoding with Apache2 mod_deflate?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-deflate

No matter how I test using different value of Accept-Encoding, it always returned as gzip.

```
curl -I -H  'Accept-Encoding: gzip' http://www.example.com
Content-Encoding: gzip


curl -I -H  'Accept-Encoding: deflate' http://www.example.com
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

So how to force deflate?

Comment: You probably don't want to use deflate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388595/why-use-deflate-instead-of-gzip-for-text-files-served-by-apache/9856879#9856879

Comment: Do you have mod_deflate enabled and configured?  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_deflate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  mod_deflate only ever responds with Content-Encoding: gzip.